# Android Command Line Tools SDK Manager on Ubuntu & java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I've downloaded the Android command line tools from: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

and I'm trying to install the sdkmanager. I keep getting the following error while trying to execute: `./tools/bin/sdkmanager`

```
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!                                   
Warning: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

I have tried updating the certificates using: `update-ca-certificates -f` still no luck.

Every solution I find that pertains to `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException` tells me to run `update-ca-certificates -f` but still.. I get the same error.

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Ubuntu Version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it what worked for me.

I had previously installed `openjdk-11` and I think this messed with my certs.

Once I purged open jdk completely and reinstalled `openjdk-8` it triggered `Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...` and downloaded a whole bunch of certificates.

When I tried to update the sdkmanager now, it worked.

Commands I ran:
`apt-get purge openjdk-*` & `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Close. I didn't purge anything, just "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk --reinstall" then "update-ca-certificates -f" and it worked after that.